# Encouraging a major GC in Java (but not a STW GC)

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am exploring a tree of stuff in Java, but I am memory limited.  I handle this by looking at occupancy stats, and when I'm over 80% (say) stop allocating new bits of the tree to avoid the OutOfMemory.  And just compute using what I've got so far using the 20% headroom.

Then every now and again I decide to move down the tree.  This *should* free up 90% of the tree I've allocated because I forget the old root and move to one of it's children.  And it does free that memory, but only if I call System.gc(), which is evil and stops my world.  But if I don't call gc() my limiting code stops me adding to my tree.

What I want to do is call out to the G1 or CMS collectors that I could really do with the old generation getting a clean, and carrying on computing and allocate new bits of the tree as the collector does it's job.

Any ideas how that can be accomplished?  Or, equally helpful, how I could avoid this artificial 80% limit, that is the root of my problem.

Comment: try to decrease Maximum Pause. The default one is 200ms, so play with the value ( -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis ) and see whether GC will cleanup more space for your app, so you don't have to call Full GC. You can also increase the number of the background threads id you have sufficient CPU power avialable ( check your JMC panel ). The flag is : -XX:ParallelGCThreads

Comment: Without a GC you don't know how much memory would be retained after a collection i.e. how much you are actually using.  If you want this level of control, you need to use unmanaged off heap memory.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent` should trigger a concurrent cycle if you invoke `System.gc()`

Alternatively you could use `-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly` for CMS which will initiate concurrent cycles once the heap reaches that threshold, since you're aiming for 80%+ occupancy that would basically continuously burn CPU time (possibly limited by `GCTimeRatio`, i'm not sure how those goals interact) to clean the old generation and thus free up memory swiftly.

The equivalent parameter for G1GC (`InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent`) already defaults to 45%, so it should already be running mixed collection cycles if you have reached that point. You should inspect GC logs to verify.

> Or, equally helpful, how I could avoid this artificial 80% limit, that is the root of my problem.

- overprovision memory, RAM is often cheaper than developer hours and GCs need some breathing room to work efficiently anyway
- consider using soft references to hold onto data that's useful but can be discarded by the GC if needed. They are not free though, so see if the extra costs are worth it.

Comment: -XX:ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent - Stellar answer, thanks, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: ... apart from the fact it doesn't actually work.  Here are some example attempts....

Comment: -Xmx4024m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGC
21:43:45.464 ? GC starting
[Full GC 2890M->459M(2183M), 4.2121752 secs]
21:43:49.677 ? GCd memory now 3737986296/4219469824(88)

Comment: -Xmx4024m -XX:+UseG1GC  -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+PrintGC
21:48:40.652 ? GC starting
[GC concurrent-mark-end, 3.0400412 secs]
[GC remark, 2.6718118 secs]
[GC cleanup 2820M->2810M(3995M), 0.0268866 secs]
[GC concurrent-cleanup-start]
[GC concurrent-cleanup-end, 0.0000689 secs]
21:48:46.473 ? GCd memory now 1271927752/4219469824(30)
21:48:46.475 ? Memory at 1271654808/4219469824(30)
21:48:48.489 ? Memory at 1234448968/4219469824(29)

Comment: -Xmx4024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC  -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+PrintGC
21:56:04.386 ? GC starting
[GC 2837710K(3478080K), 2.3043713 secs]
21:56:13.575 ? GCd memory now 3652152264/4149739520(88)
21:56:13.578 ? Memory at 3651545752/4149739520(87)

Comment: So it seems that it doesn't do the full GC (good!), but the resulting pause is worse than stopping the world.  Even if you get the max pause on the G1 collector.  Worse, with the G1 collector, it doesn't actually free up the memory either.

Comment: -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly DOES seem to work though. Maybe not ideal, as I'd prefer to use the G1 collector (I read a lot of good things about it).  But for the minute the solves my immediate problem.

Comment: Log output in comments is quite unreadable. If you need clarification you probably should amend your question.